# Pseudoclass on child conditional on data attribute of parent

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I am trying to disable a button dynamically based on a data attribute that's present on the body, code looks sort of like this:

```
<body data-online="true">
  <button disabled></button>
</body>
```

What I want is to set the pseudoclass disabled based on the value of the body's data attribute. I'm looking for the simplest possible way to do this. I know that conventionally this would be done asynchronously with JS, but for annoying reasons I have no direct control over I would prefer another way. I'm wondering if it's possible to set the pseudoclass directly through CSS or HTML in some way?

Comment: body[data-online=true]>button{
 pointer-events: none;
  opacity: .65;
} the body which contain data-online=true will disabled don't use disabled in button

Comment: div[data-online='true'] > button{ pointer-events: none; opacity: .65; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't this it is possible to achieve this without any JavaScript since the disabled properly is a boolean attribute.

You'll need at least to grab the element using JavaScript and conditionally apply the disabled attribute. As on the code below:

```
function checkButtonDisabled() {
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  const button = document.querySelector('#btn')
  const buttonIsDisabled = body.getAttribute('data-online') === 'true'
  
  if (buttonIsDisabled) {
    button.setAttribute("disabled", true)
    return
  }
  
  button.removeAttribute("disabled")
}

checkButtonDisabled()
```

Although, If your intention is also to style it, you could use the selector below or some variant that could suit better for you:

```
body[data-online="true"] > button {
  /* Your styles here */
}
```

you could check this article also which [explains attribute selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).

Comment: Thanks, yeah I am currently using a combination of JS selectors (as well as pointer-events: none for certain other items in this app, like links that need to be disabled), but I was hoping there was a way I could avoid JS altogether.

The problem with pointer-events: none is that it still allows for tabbing and pressing enter, and also makes it difficult to enable cursor changes (since cursor changes are themselves pointer events). It seems there is no easier way to do this in this case. Thanks for the help.